# How can I use the FirstOrDefaultAsync method within the method?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await, xunit

When I run it by replacing the FirstOrDefaultAsync method with FirstOrDefault, the test works as expected. In other words, when I remove the asynchronous structure, my test runs correctly. However, when in the asynchronous structure and entering the .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync() method, the test exits without waiting for the asynchronous structure, resulting in an incorrect test. How can I use the FirstOrDefaultAsync structure in XUnit testing?

```
public async Task<BaseResponseModel<StatusResponse>> GetDetail(GetDetailRequest request)
{
   _userId = _userSessionService.GetUserId();
    int exTypeId = TrackingExamTypeEnumFromSessionType(request.TypeId);

   //other methods

   UserExam userExam = await _persistenceContext.Query<UserExam>()
      .AsNoTracking()
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.UserId == _userId &&
                           d.ExamId == request.ExamId &&
                           (int)d.Type == exTypeId);

}

public class Test{

  private readonly ExamService _examService;

  private readonly Mock<Context> _context = new Mock<Context>();
    
  public Test{
    
          _examService = new ExamService{
      
          _context.Object
        }
        }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetTrialExamDetail_WithoutTestSections_ReturnsCorrectResponse()
    {
      // Arrange
      var request = new GetDetailRequest
      {
          ExamId = 1,
          STypeId = Enums.SessionType.A
      };

      _context.Setup(c => c.Query<Test>()).Returns(new List<Test>()
      {
          new Test
          {
              ExamId = 1,
              Url = "test"
          }
      }.AsQueryable());

      _context.Setup(p => p.GetListFromCache<ExamTest>(
      It.IsAny<string>(),
      null))
      .Returns((string cacheKey, TimeSpan? slidingExpiration) =>
      {
          return new List<ExamTest>();
      });
      

        // Act
        var result = await _examService.GetDetail(request);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(Enums.ResponseStatus.Success, result.ResponseStatus);
        Assert.Equal(Enums.ResponseStatus.Success.ToString(), result.ResponseMessage);
        Assert.Empty(result.ResponseData.Exams);
    }

}
```

How can I use the FirstOrDefaultAsync structure in XUnit testing?

Comment: You don't appear to be returning anything from `GetDetail()`.

Comment: Please share the implementation of `_examService.GetDetail`. Ideally full [mre].

Comment: What version of xUnit are you using? If there is a problem with the test framework not handling asynchronous tests correctly, it should be reproducible with something as simple as `await Task.Delay(20); Assert.Fail();`